# Join with missing lines

Tags: linux, command-line

Suppose I have two files that look like this:

File 1:

```
1 x
2 y
3 z
5 l
```

File 2:

```
1 a
2 b
4 c
5 c
```

And I want to join them using the first column as a key to give

```
1 x a
2 y b
3 z
4 c
5 l c
```

where a missing line in one file just means that I omit its data.  I thought `join` would do the trick, but it seems to insist on skipping any line that doesn't appear in both files and I can't find an option to make it do otherwise.  AT least `-e` didn't work how I thought it would.  What's the right command line way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible with the `join` command using the `-a` option (twice, once for each file number). Example:

```
join -a1 -a2 1.txt 2.txt
```

Comment: @pythonicmetaphor It didn't explicitly mention using `-a` twice.